# Opencart 1.5.5.1 : Not sending confirmation emails

Tags: php, opencart

My opencart is not sending out confirmation emails. I am using mail(), not smtp.
Tried sending mail trough custom php file and it works fine, therefore there is no problems with the server.

**Settings** (empty):

[image]

**EDIT : Solved the problem. Check the answer.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the problem.

Change the file:

> system/library/**mail.php**  | line **97**

Remove **second** `$this->newline` from code.

```
$header .= 'Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary="' . $boundary . '"' . $this->newline . $this->newline;
```

Final look:

```
$header .= 'Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary="' . $boundary . '"' . $this->newline;
```

It works just fine for me now.

Answer (score 0):

For me, it was also a server issue.

I made the amendments to mail.php and I also had the error

sendmail: fatal: chdir /var/spool/postfix: Permission denied

showing up in /var/log/httpd/error_log.  This was caused by the apache user not having SELinux permission to send email. This could also occur on other distributions which use SELinux (particularly Fedora and CentOS, but possibly others as well), if it is set to "Enforcing".

You can check this by using

/usr/sbin/getsebool httpd_can_sendmail
which will report

httpd_can_sendmail --> {on|off}

and if it is off, you can turn it on using
sudo setsebool -P httpd_can_sendmail 1
with the "-P" for persistent (across reboots).

Hope this helps someone!